# How to update modified date and time with log4j in Java?

Tags: java, log4j

My Java program runs in a loop every 5 minutes.

I am using log4j for logging. When writing new rows in the log file, the modified date and time of the file is not updated even if I close and reopen the program. The modified date and time is only updated if you open the log file with another program such as Visual Studio Code.

At the beginning of the Java class I'm initializing the logger like this:

`private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger (getClass().getName());`

Is there any way to update the modified date and time of the log file at each iteration of the loop?

Environment: Windows 10

Comment: That is a problem of Windows, not refreshing the Explorer window when a file is updated. This is not a programming issue, nor a Java issue. It's just how Windows works. Have you tried pressing F5 to refresh the the Explorer window?

Comment: Go to the folder where your file is, in windows explorer, right click and hit "refresh". The last updated date for the file should change.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Yes, but same problem date and time has not updated.. it's a big problem because I use opmanager to see if log has been written or modified, but without updated modified date and time opmanager fires an alert.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a conceptual answer rather than an actual solution, but I'll give it a try for future viewers since I'm experiencing a related issue.

The rules of updating the `Last Modified` attribute of a file depends on the operation and file system. I could not find an official knowledge base but here's [someone who actually tested it on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46428666/3367818).

**Bottom line is that you cannot trust `Date Modified` for specifying a content change that has been made to a file.**

Since my goal was to monitor (through a designated application) `.log` files to see if my service was down, I ended up actually checking the first tokens of the last line of the code (which contained the date and time). Another solution to this problem would be to use [DailyRollingFileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) that would rollover a new file every day.

If you still want to rely on `Date Modified`, then you'll have to `touch` the file manually. [Here's how to get the actual file from your Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4401387/3367818), then you can use [java.io.File.setLastModified()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setLastModified%28long%29).

Hope it helps.